# Phonegap/jQuery mobile - protocol "sms:" send to multiple numbers

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, sms, phonegap-build

Is there a possibility to head the new SMS window with multiple numbers?
I tested with these codes:

```
<a href="sms:aaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccc">SMS</a>
<a href="sms:aaaaaaaaaa;bbbbbbbbbb;cccccccccc">SMS</a>
```

But it does not work on ios.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to my tests and also the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html).

> The sms scheme is used to launch the Messages app. The format for URLs
>   of this type is “sms:”, where  is an optional parameter
>   that specifies the target phone number of the SMS message. **This
>   parameter can contain the digits 0 through 9 and the plus (+), hyphen
>   (-), and period (.) characters.**